# Get Oauth token of googleAPI with REST client

Tags: rest, google-api, google-api-client, google-sheets-api

I am going to use Google Sheet API. I want test it with a REST client, so, first at all, I want an example of how to get the oAuth token. No need to give me the Google API doc because it didn't help me so much.

For example I don't know what to put in "redirect_uri" or "state". Can anyone provide me a full example of how to get the token by http REST client?

Comment: Welcome to stack please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  You will need to edit your question showing us what you have tried and describing any issues you are having.    We are not here to supply you with an example sorry that is what the documentation is for.

Answer (score 2):

**I am going to use Google Sheet API. I want test it with a REST client, so, first at all, I want an example of how to get the oAuth token. No need to give me the Google API doc because it didn't help me so much.**

I'll give you a quick sample on how to use REST client with Sheets API v4 and generate token as well. You'll also learn how to perform [basic Sheets v4 operation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/samples/reading).

1. Go to [oauthplayground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/). Scroll down to Google Sheets v4.
2. Choose the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` permission. Click *Authorize APIs* and Allow access.
3. On Step 2, Click *Exchange Authorization Code for Tokens*. Now this will generate access tokens. This token has a lifecycle of 3600 seconds.
4. In the Request URI textfield, paste this:

https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}/values/{Sheet1}!A1

*replace *Sheet1* with the name of your sheet and *spreadsheetId* with ID of spreadsheet.

This REST call will return the value of A1 cell. You've just learned how to fetch for cell values using REST.

Check this [JS Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/js) to apply this on the web using JS.